# Focus on HTML Select dropdown option after GET request

Tags: php, html

So I am making a programme and I am submitting a form to itself. This programme is a very basic calculator as I am new to HTML and PHP. I am trying to make it so that when you submit the form, the Select dropdown will remain on the most recently used operator.

For example, if I make the calculator do '5 + 5', then I want the submitted form to keep the operator dropdown on '+'.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// grab the form values from $_HTTP_GET_VARS hash extract($_GET);

// first compute the output, but only if data has been input if(isset($calc) && $operator == "multiply") { // $calc exists as a variable
        $prod = $x * $y;    } elseif (isset($calc) && $operator == "plus") {
        $operator = $plus;
        $prod = $x + $y;    } elseif (isset($calc) && $operator == "minus") {
        $operator = "minus";
        $prod = $x - $y;    } elseif (isset($calc) && $operator == "divide") {
        $sign = "/";
        $prod = $x / $y;    } else { // set defaults
      $x=0;
      $y=0;
      $prod=0;    } ?>

<html>    <head>
      <title>PHP Calculator Example</title>    </head>

   <body>

      <h3>PHP Calculator (Version 1)</h3>
      <p>Multiply two numbers and output the result</p>

      <form method="get" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
         <label for="x">x = </label>
         <input type="text" name="x" id="x" size="5" value="<?php print $x; ?>"/>
         
         <select name="operator" id="operator">
            <option value="plus">+</option>
            <option value="minus">-</option>
            <option value="divide">/</option>
            <option value="multiply">*</option>
        </select>

        <label for="y">y = </label>
        <input type="text" name="y" id="y" size="5" value="<?php print $y; ?>"/>


         <input type="submit" name="calc" value="Calculate"/>
      </form>

      <!-- print the result -->
      <?php if(isset($calc)) {

         print "<p>x $sign y = $prod</p>";

      } ?>

   </body> </html>
```

Comment: You add an attribute selected to the <option> that you want the dropdown to start out with. E.g `<option value="multiply" <?php if ($operator==="multiply") echo "selected";?>>*</option>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to remain on option selected in the select element
The option has to have an attribute "selected"

```
<select name="operator" id="operator">
    <option <?php if(isset($_GET['operator']) && $_GET['operator'] == "plus"){echo "selected";} ?> value="plus">+</option>
    <option <?php if(isset($_GET['operator']) && $_GET['operator'] == "minus"){echo "selected";} ?> value="minus">-</option>
    <option <?php if(isset($_GET['operator']) && $_GET['operator'] == "divide"){echo "selected";} ?> value="divide">/</option>
    <option <?php if(isset($_GET['operator']) && $_GET['operator'] == "multiply"){echo "selected";} ?> value="multiply">*</option>
</select>
```

Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution employing javascript would be this

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['operator'])) {
       ?>
   <script>document.getElementById("operator").value = '<?=$_GET['operator']?>';</script>
       <?php
   }
 ?>
```